# Unsure how to overwrite a callback to adjust unexported field

Tags: go, discord

What I'd like to do is overwrite some boolean values on a given object, such as:

```
func main() {
    manager := dshardmanager.New("Bot " + token)
    manager.bareSession.State.TrackRoles = false;
    manager.bareSession.State.TrackPresences = false;

    // more stuff happens down here
}
```

However `bareSession` is an unexported field, so I need to do this differently from what I'm gathering.  I've come across some approaches using reflection but I'd like to learn the *best practices* approach to doing this.

In my specific case, it looks like the [library I'm using offers a method to accomplish this](https://github.com/jonas747/dshardmanager/blob/master/dshardmanager.go#L53).  I've been tinkering with how to overwrite/define such a method but can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

**What's the ideal approach to defining [this `SessionFunc()`](https://github.com/jonas747/dshardmanager/blob/master/dshardmanager.go#L53) to customize the session the way I'm trying to?**

Comment: Nowhere in that code is `SessionFunc` handling `bareSession`. `bareSession` is set once [here](https://github.com/jonas747/dshardmanager/blob/9e4282faed43932341980f0e5f11fa88e73b04a2/dshardmanager.go#L78) and from then on it's only read from. It seems to be intended not to be touched. Using `reflect` and `unsafe` you could set it's fields however that is something you should avoid doing at all cost.

Comment: ... if there isn't any other 3rd party package that allows you to do what you need, you have the option to fork the project and simply export the `bareSession` field.

Comment: "I'd like to learn the best practices approach to doing this" - is not to. The "best practice" is don't tinker with unexported members. That's why unexported members exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the context of that library, so I'm not sure if what I'll write here makes sense for you :) But by looking at the API, `SessionFunc` is a `func(token string) (*discordgo.Session, error)`, i.e., a function which receives a `string` and returns a `Session` and an `error`. So you can make something like this to override it:

```
func main() {
    manager := dshardmanager.New("Bot " + token)
    manager.SessionFunc = func(token string) (*discordgo.Session, error) {
        // use "token"

        // if invalid:
        if token == "" {
            // return an error
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid token")
        }

        // otherwise, return a valid session
        return &discordgo.Session{}
    }

    // more stuff happens down here
}
```

The code is obviously very generic, but the main idea is that you need to define that function with that exact header, and implement it. I don't know how you can, for example, evaluate the token parameter or create a `discordgo.Session`. Or how you can configure the `TrackRoles` or `TrackPresences` values by using `SessionFunc`. That's very specific for that library only, but I guess it makes more sense to you than to me :)

You could also define a regular function elsewhere with that exact header:

```
func createNewSession(token string) (*discordgo.Session, error) {
    // use "token"

    // if invalid:
    if token == "" {
        // return an error
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid token")
    }

    // otherwise, return a valid session
    return &discordgo.Session{}
}
```

And set it with:

```
func main() {
    manager := dshardmanager.New("Bot " + token)
    manager.SessionFunc = createNewSession

    // more stuff happens down here
}
```

Both approaches work the same way.

Reflection is [almost] never the recommended way to do those things, if the library creators made those properties private, they shouldn't be changed/accessed from outside.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks.  Is there a way for me to "extend" `SessionFunc` without having to duplicate the logic in my code?

Comment: I just checked the code for dshardmanager, there's the function StdSessionFunc which contains the default implementation for SessionFunc, so you can call it inside your own custom function (i.e. s, err := manager.StdSessionFunc(token) ... )

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow you to change `bareSession`. But if you need to derive a new `*discordgo.Session` with custom parameters you can do something similar to as follows.

```
func MySessionFunc(m *dshardmanager.Manager) dshardmanager.SessionFunc {
    return func(token string) (*discordgo.Session, error) {
        //Call default Session allocator
        s, err := m.StdSessionFunc(token)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        //Then, change its exported fields
        s.State.TrackRoles = false
        s.TrackPresences = false
        return s, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    manager := dshardmanager.New("Bot " + token)
    manager.SessionFunc = MySessionFunc(manager)
}
```